# How to do Elastic Search in MySQL without using an external PHP Library?

Tags: php, mysql, elasticsearch

I created a **Movie Library Database** in MySQL. I also created a **PHP REST API** for getting data as JSON, That drives my app.

Currently, The movie search works using the **LIKE Statement In MySQL**. But it doesn't provide a broad elastic search

For instance, If a movie name is

**THE AMAZING SPIDERMAN**
I wan't to get the record by any of the searches like

1. the
2. amaz
3. spider man
4. the spider man
5. amazing the
6. amaz spider

I don't have SSH and Composer access on my host. How should I change my SQL Query to return results like this. I thing to go for REGEX? What kind of a REGEX match here?

My current query is

```
$q=$_POST["q"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM AudioReg WHERE Name LIKE '$q%';
```

Which works like normal search only. My complete PHP code is

```
<?php
include "Database.php";
$q=$_POST["q"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM AudioReg WHERE Name LIKE '$q%' ORDER BY RAND()";  
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$json=array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $json[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($json);
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: I don't think that this is work for MySQL, think about using ElasticSearch or Sphinx

Comment: Can't any REGEX help? I don't have access to Composer on my Host

Comment: I don't think so. Perhaps some regexp-guru can help you, but as for me it's work for normal search engine. BTW it's not about composer. ElasticSearch is not just a library which you can plug in via composer: https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch

Comment: Please check https://github.com/hkulekci/node-app-with-elasticsearch application to find similar ideas. In this demo, there is an RDMS based application, and I used Logstash to move data to integrate ES. You should not use any library to use Elasticsearch. On the other hand, you can apply PHP Curl directly to reach ES API. But this is not suggested.